# Azure devops, how to I find all users and groups who have permission to delete a repository?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Well one way could be to go to the project setting and then click repository and then

- check all the groups it has,
- Read into each group and identify the ones have access to delete repository
- Then go into that that group and find members
- if member is user: store/list/write-down (may be in excel)
- else if member is group, go recursively inside it to find all users it may have

But that's quite a manual process. I am looking for a azure CLI or rest api on which I can query and it gives me back the results. Something like SQL : find all users on repository=xyz where permission=delete

The intent is to create a periodic audit process.

Comment: there is a new public preview related to auditing: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/auditing-for-azure-devops-is-now-in-public-preview/. not sure if relevant for you

Comment: @old-monk Haven't heard from you for a while. Did Leo's solution answer your question? You can accept it if it helps.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT thanks for your interest but I can't accept that as an answer. I understand a direct, as such query is impossible now but I hoping for a workaround that can be automated/scripted. Also the shared link 'Set Version con....' is about setting/writing but I am concerned about making a query, hence my question doesn't align with that feature request. I have posted one more in their forum: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/831524/azure-devops-how-to-i-find-all-users-and-groups-wh-1.html

Comment: Let me know if you have found a way to do this. I need to do a similar audit.

Answer (score 1):

> But that's quite a manual process. I am looking for a azure CLI or rest api on which I can query and it gives me back the results.

I am afraid we could not achieve it by rest api at this moment.

That because **there is no such REST API to set version control permissions** (including git repo). There is a user voice about it on our main forum for product suggestions:

[Set version control permissions by REST API](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365828/set-version-control-permissions-by-rest-api.html)

You could  vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Even if we have that API, there is still a long way to go to complete it. First, we need to traverse all the eligible groups and users according to the condition `Delete repository=Allow`, then filter the groups from the result of the traversal, and call the API according to the filtered group ID to get the users in the group. Last, we still have to merge those duplicate user names. So, this should be a long way to do it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. My thought process is that, their is set of manual steps to do it, based on how Microsoft has designed most of it, their must (or hopefully) be some kind of API calls or may have some corresponding CLI calls to interact with those functions.